# I can't consume moodle services. Respond accessexception

Tags: moodle-api

I'm trying to consume Moodle web services but they respond accessexception. I already generated the Token and enabled the web services from the Moodle administration module.

my endpoint

`http://MyMoodle/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_group_get_course_user_groups&wstoken={my_token}`

is returning the following exception:

```
{
    "exception": "webservice_access_exception",
    "errorcode": "accessexception",
    "message": "Excepción al control de acceso"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, You should share the specific code that is causing this error to be called, not a link to your model, if you want assistance

Comment: Hi - Here's a great checklist of possible causes: https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Web_services_FAQ#What_is_the_.27Access_control_exception.27_error  .  One area to check out: even if web services are enabled and the token is generated, the user must be permitted to call certain functions. Hope this is helpful!